# Css not working in javascript print function

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a javascript function to print a especific div called by a button.It works like i want but without styling.The problem is when i try to add the div style to the function,the print preview show a blank page in Chrome(Firefox works well).My function code is:

```
    function printDiv(event) {
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById("page-wrap");

   var html = '<html><head>'+
              '<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>'+
              '</head><body style="background:#ffffff;">'+
              DocumentContainer.innerHTML+'</body></html>';

    var WindowObject = window.open("", "PrintWindow",
    "width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
    WindowObject.document.writeln(html);
    WindowObject.document.close();   
    WindowObject.print();
    WindowObject.close(); 
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the css media query

```
 @media print
```

And apply styles you want in print

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function() { objWin.print(); objWin.close(); }, 100);
```